# increase/decrease number in a cell by clicking in a range of cells - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

need some help here...

I´m trying to help my wife automate excel spreadsheet shes uses, and im not being able to solve this...

**What i want to achieve:**

*When i click in a range of cells, i want that a specific number decrease in a cell and increase in other cell, at the same time.*

**In the example:**

I insert number **22** in cell D4  (this define the maximum cells that will become selected)

When i click on a cell in that range off cells, this cell becomes green and the number in cell D4 decrease by one and in cell F4 the number increase by one, and so on for every cell in that range in a maximum off 22 clicks.

If i click the same cell again, the cell comes to normal (without the green overlay), and the number in cells D4 increase by one and in F4 decrease by one, do, do the inverse.

After 22 cells are selected and overlayed with green, if i continue to click nothing happen, for me to be able to make another cell green, i need to remove one of the previous selected cells.

i hope you guys understand...

I only have a code to change cell color by double click , and the spreasheet dont use any other code, only conditional formatting and formulas.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Please check the examples pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What your try to achieve requires macro. Asking for entire macro is off-topic here, being too broad. You need to try writing it yourself and may ask specific question during that if necessary.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear. What defines the range of cells in which you can click cells in order to toggle their color. You have only mentioned D4 and F4 as the count down and count up cells. Are you looking for a VBA solution?

Comment: Yes, im looking for a VBA solution, i have now a code that i turn the cell to green on double click.  but i cannot make code to make it increase or decrease and limit the amount off cells i can select and change color...                      
                                                                                                                      
sorry, maybe im just beeing to ambicious.  im not really an expert, im new at this, and im trying to help my wife... thats why im asking for help.   thanks guys

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1426241/edit) to include the code and explain exactly what the problem is with it

Comment: Thanks cybernetic.nomad, i actually only have the code to change the cell color by double click.. like i said above, maybe i´m beeing to ambicious on this, its out of my league...

Comment: Thanks Máté Juhász, like i said, im new, and i only have the above code, i have shared in post now... i really dont know how to do what i wnant to do, or even if its possible to do it...  thanks

Comment: So are you saying that you know how to write a VBA routine that triggers on double-click, knows what cell was clicked, and changes the color of that cell, but you need to know how to *access the **values*** in cells? You might want to run [this search](https://superuser.com/search?q=excel%2A+vba), which will lead you to nearly four thousand Super User posts about Excel and VBA.  Hundreds of them have good examples of working code (you might want to sort by votes).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a couple of simple formulas on those Quantity cells.

First, in `Quantity to Insert` have the following: `= 21 - Quantity_Inserted`.

Second, in `Quantity Inserted` have the following: `=COUNTIFS(Range, "x")`

This will count the number of `x` in your `Range` and display it in the `Quantity Inserted` field, while at the same time subtracting that same amount from `Quantity to Insert` field.

I don't have a lot of experience (really, none at all) with VBA, but since you already have code to change the cell colour on a double-click, it's probably not going to take too much work to have it insert an 'x' instead.

Alternatively, you could have a conditional formatting applied to `Range` to detect whenever an `x` has been placed and colour both the text and background yellow effectively hiding the fact there's an `x` that's being counted.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, i will try the formulas as you suggested, but the problem i see, is that in her spreadsheet, this cells will have numbers, like the days of the week or of the month.. so i cannot put the X, but maybe i can use your aproach to try to solve my problem.  i will make some tests.  thanks again

Comment: Oooh, that would have been useful information to include in the question! I'll have a think and update my answer if I can figure it out...

Comment: You are right, i´m sorry, im new at this... im learning :)  but your answer helped me, i can already do what i want, the way you said.    I  just need a similar formula to detect color in a cell and count it, instead of the X.  and it will work like a charm.  thanks again :)

Comment: Detecting colour in a cell is trickier, and will probably require some VBA.

Comment: Yes, probably... I have found a code to detect color and change the value of cell by one, now I just need to implement the two codes.

I'm making tests, and later I share the code here if I make it work.

Thanks again